# How to access Java dependency on command line?

Tags: java, command-line, resources

I have a moderately old, small Java application which has an option to read and export PDF files using the Apache PDFBox library (hereunder, "pdfbox-app.jar"). All the files, including this resource, are stored in a single flat folder.

This works fine when called from a JAR file:

```
D:\Prog\!GitHub\Arena>java -jar Athena.jar NPCGenerator -p
OED NPC Generator
-----------------
Writing Gwenllian-ElfFtr1Wiz1.pdf
```

It similarly works fine when run from my IDE (jGrasp).

But it fails when called from the command line, outside of its JAR:

```
D:\Prog\!GitHub\Arena>java NPCGenerator -p
OED NPC Generator
-----------------
Writing Eoin-HalflingFtr1.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDoc
ument
        at CharacterPDF.writePDF(CharacterPDF.java:49)
        at NPCGenerator.printToPDF(NPCGenerator.java:294)
        at NPCGenerator.makeAllNPCs(NPCGenerator.java:270)
        at NPCGenerator.main(NPCGenerator.java:308)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.j
ava:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader
s.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 4 more
```

What should I be doing to run this on the command line outside of its own JAR?

Comment: You should look for the manifest file inside the Jar file, it will have the dependencies listed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the pdfbox jar, and any other dependencies, on the classpath:

```
java -classpath .;pdfbox-app.jar NPCGenerator -p
```

Without that, Java doesn't know where to look for `org/apache/pdfbox` classes. It looks for `.class` files relative to the default classpath (which is just `.`, the current directory), but does not look inside jars.

Comment: depending on the OS, use ":" instead of ";" .

Comment: Thanks. I was very close, but it's the ".;" syntax that I didn't know about.